# How do I call DateJS' Date.parse() in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, date, datejs

How do I call DateJS' Date.parse() in Java?

This is what I am using:

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        scriptEngine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("date.js"));

        System.out.println(scriptEngine.eval("Date.parse(\"3/12/1998\").toString();"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Thu Mar 12 1998 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Is there a better way to call Date.parse() in Java?

DateJS:
http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: Why are you using a JavaScript parsing library instead of a Java one - say, [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Doesn't Joda Time require date format to parse?
DateJS doesn't require date formats.

Comment: No matter what library you use, if you don't specify a date format, then the library can only take a best-guess attempt at parsing the date. Case in point, the string `"3/12/1998"` in your code is ambiguous, and could parse to March 12, 1998 or December 3, 1998, depending on the locale.

Comment: That is not a problem because I only need to specify "date.js", which is US only. DateJS supports over 150 locales: simply specify "date-en-US.js", "date-de-DE.js", "date-fr-FR.js", etc...

DateJS is easier for me because I don't have to manually generate a list of possible date formats.

Comment: Fair enough. My gut reaction is just that there's got to be a better solution than running JavaScript in Java - it feels like a major WTF. Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389348/parse-any-date-in-java)?

Answer (score 1):

What about:

`Date date new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").parse(outputFromFile);`

*yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss is not the correct, pattern, it is only an example*

---

You could write a list of date format patterns and try to parse them until one did not rise an exception.

Comment: I tried SimpleDateFormat, but it is restricted to the date format.

Comment: @XP1 what do you mean by: "is restricted to the date format"? - Did I understand the question wrong: you want to parse a date?

Comment: If the date format pattern does not match, then I have to find the correct date format pattern. DateJS detects the date automatically. In my question, I wanted to know the best way, or if there is another way, to call the JavaScript method Date.parse() from DateJS in Java without calling eval().

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat` is overkill here.  Regular [`DateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) is more than sufficient:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;

public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).parse("3/12/1998").toString());
    }
}
```

Outputs `Thu Mar 12 00:00:00 EST 1998`

The problem comes up when you don't know what date format the user is entering.  None of Java's common date/time libraries seem to have any way of parsing those... at least the built-in and JodaTime ones don't.

You may have some luck with the accepted answer to the question [PHP's strtotime() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1268174/15880)