# unix "date --date=..." in Java

Tags: java, unix, date

I there a way to instantiate <strike>a Date object</strike> any date representation in Java with input similar to the Unix

```
date --date='...'
```

that can figure out things like *yesterday, tomorrow, next thursday* etc?

I've tried to search this on Google, but it doesn't come up with anything related, as it's quite hard to explain what I'm looking for.

**EDIT** probably it was misleading, I don't want a suggestion on how to create a method myself, I'm looking for a working library/code.

**EDIT 2** having in mind that PHP `strtotime` does exactly the same thing, I searched and this time it gave me a great [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268174/phps-strtotime-in-java) and I'm probably gonna stick to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a util method using [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

for example :

```
public enum DateUtilKeyWords{
 YESTERDAY;
}

public static Date getDate(DateUtilKeyWords dateUtilKeyWord) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    switch (dateUtilKeyWord) {
        case YESTERDAY: {
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean java.util.Calendar. It doesn't accept input like 'yesterday', does it?

Comment: Well, the problem with your approach is that I have to implement it and then debug it too. I asked for an out-of-the-box Java alternative to unix `date --date=` command, like the PHP `strtotime` function.

Comment: you can also put it to native if you are on unix and grab the string output and parse it to date