# Comprehensive (Intelligent) Date library

Tags: java, internationalization

I'm looking for a complete Date management library in java that would allow me to understand strings like :

- Tomorrow at noon => 2011-10-20 12:00
- Today at 4pm => 2011-10-20 16:00

etc...

But it would be *perfect* if this lib would also be Internationalized. I plan to use it in many languages, and "just" english wouldn't be enough.

I already found http://www.datejs.com/ as a possibility, but it's for Javascript (client)'s side. I'm looking for something in Server side.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think "Tomorrow at noon" makes more sense than "lunch". Meal times tend to vary wildly across different cultures :)

Comment: And Hobbits even eat 3 lunches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An similar question was at [PHP's strtotime() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268174/phps-strtotime-in-java) and here's a good answer. @dfa did an object that do exactly what I'm looking for, you can find the link [here](https://bitbucket.org/dfa/strtotime/wiki/Home)

Answer (score 1):

[PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.com/prettytime/) is what you need

Comment: OK, could you give an example on how to *parse* such "pretty" values? I believe this is what the question is about...

Comment: In fact I was just looking for a library that could help me archive that. But if you want examples, I found them at http://ocpsoft.com/prettytime/#examples

Comment: I removed the Accepted because apparently this lib does the opposite : you give a date, it returns the date as textual. What I'm looking for is a lib that would return an object Date from a String.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily build that yourself with e.g. [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Do you have an example on how to do it? I know Joda Time, but can't see how this could help me achieve the way I want :/ Thanks!