# How algorithm of  strtotime(PHP Date function) Works?

Tags: php, algorithm, date, time, persian

1. i wanna to know how ***strtotime***  (php Date function) work?
2. how Parse string Like "*15 September 2012*" to timeStamp
3. is there any better algorithm?

my purpose is changing this function for Persian Language

Comment: Here is http://stackoverflow.com/a/1268380 a Java implementation, but do not know if it is taken directly from the source code of PHP strtotime function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can browse the source code of PHP ( https://github.com/php/php-src) and search function to see its implementation.

**UPDATE**

Here is the algorithm of the function strtotime () https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L1324

Regards!.

Comment: Instead of linking to master (which will change over time, and break your link) here is a link to the 5.3.23 tag instead. This won't change. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.3.23/ext/date/php_date.c#L1397

Answer (score 4):

The method that actually parses the string is in [parse_date.re's `scan()` method](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3152d44b361ce528368ca4f57111315b2fa324bd/ext/date/lib/parse_date.re#L847). There you will find all `strtotime` keywords and their behaviors.

That library is included from https://github.com/derickr/timelib.

Answer (score 3):

since *strtotime* accepts English input, I'd recommend taking the Persian input:
"15 (SOMETHING_PERSIAN) 2012" and replace the required string (you need some RegExp and a switch statement, I guess) and make it "15 (SOMETHING_ENGLISH) 2012" and THEN send it to *strtotime*

Comment: the problem is that i wanna to change sth like " فروردین 12 2004 " into ex 2004/6/12

Comment: by using RegExp you'll find that string and replace it with the corresponding English equivalent

Comment: persian language is more complicated  .... i prefer to rewrite this function ....

Answer (score 3):

> i wanna to know how strtotime (php Date function) work?

Go here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c

Search for `timelib_strtotime`.

Comment: The source file is 25,000 lines long, clearly generated by a yacc/bison-like tool.  Although it may be adequate as a working implementation, it is not useful as any sort of resource for learning how to it is actually done.

Comment: I've tried to look into that source code, and I felt like abyss is staring back at me.

Comment: One probably rather wants to look at https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/2bf451b92594a70fe745b9d27783ffe211d7940e/ext/date/lib/parse_date.re - that's the file used to generate the C code.

Answer (score 2):

forget about it, use php Intl extension. in future will be a part of php core.

```php
<?php
    // format
    $format = datefmt_create('fa_IR@calendar=persian', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Asia/Tehran', IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm');

    // time in locale as you wish
    var_dump(datefmt_format($format, time())); // '۱۳۹۱/۰۲/۰۴ ۱۹:۱۵'
```

support ICU project if you want to support Persian in i18n for all languages.

[php intl extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)

[icu-project.org](http://icu-project.org)